# Calculate X, Y, Z of the 4 points in the 3D space.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, plane-geometry

I want to find the $x, y, z$ coordinates for $4$ points in a 3D space. Point $A$ is my origin $(X, Y, Z = 0,0,0)$ and other points $B, C, D$ are with reference to point A. I know all six distances from  $A \to B,  A\to C,  A\to D,  B\to C,  B\to D$, and  $C\to D$.

Point $B$ lies on axis $X$, point $C$ lies in $XY$ plane, and lastly, point $D$ can be anywhere.

Coordinates of the points $A, B, C, D$ are as follows:

$A = (0, 0, 0)$

$B = (X_B, 0, 0)$

$C = (X_C, Y_C, 0)$

$D = (X_D, Y_D, Z_D)$

It is straightforward to determine $X_B$, $X_C$, and $Y_C$. I am having difficulty finding X, Y, Z coordinate of the point D with respect to the point A.

To determine Xd, Yd, Zd, I am using the following equations

$(X_D-X_A)^2 + (Y_D-Y_A)^2 + (Z_D-Z_A)^2 = AD^2$

$(X_D-X_B)^2 + (Y_D-Y_B)^2 + (Z_D-Z_B)^2 = BD^2$

$(X_D-X_C)^2 + (Y_D-Y_C)^2 + (Z_D-Z_C)^2 = CD^2$

After doing some expansion and eliminating the 2nd order variables I came up with the following:

$Ax = b$

$x = (X_D, Y_D, Z_D)$

after doing the pseudo inverse on both sides I can solve for x. I am not sure if my method of solving $X_D$, $Y_D$, and $Z_D$ is correct.

[4 points diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FpmL.jpg)

Comment: your method is correct, just be aware that you can have multiple solutions (for example, point $B'$ can have coordinates $(-X_B,0,0)$, etc.). Also sometimes there is no solution (triangle inequality).

Comment: Yes you are correct, it can have multiple solutions but for the Points B and C, I am assuming that corresponding planes are positive.